# Why is xlrd reading the wrong number of columns?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

When I read an .xls file, xlrd acts as if there was an empty column at position 0, and the last column (number 58, if counting from 0) is never read; the first column is skipped and the last one disappears.

The issue goes away when I save the file (either as an .xls or .xlsx) and do the whole process again. When saving, Excel tells me that there may be compatibility issues. I need to automate this process, which is why I'd like to avoid manually having to save the file.

```py
# Loading the 'converted' file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(converted_file_path) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

print('Row',len(sheet.row(3)),sheet.row(3))
# Prints: Row 59 [text:'Client Number', ...


# Loading the original file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(original_file_path) 
print('Row',len(sheet.row(3)),sheet.row(3))
# Prints: Row 58 [empty:'', text:'Client Number', ...

print(sheet.cell_value(0,5))
# Prints nothing, while there is a number at cell (0,5)
```

Comment: Are you able use something like pastebin to give us a link to a file that doesn't work?

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't; it contains very sensible data for the company I work for. And I can't edit it out because then the file would work.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you could automate the loading and saving to `.xlsx` format using Python `win32com` by using Excel itself. Then it should be able to be read normally using `xlrd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin for suggesting the `win32com` fix, but I found the actual problem. It has something to do with how `xlrd` has Python load up sheets in memory. Perhaps messing around with the `on_demand` parameter while loading the workbook does something, but anyhow, here's what was happening:

I needed the sheet named "Report X" where X is some number, so I looked for it like this:

```py
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    if 'Report' in sheet.name:
        report_sheet = sheet
        break
```

Then, I changed it to

```py
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    if 'Report' in sheet.name:
        report_sheet = sheet
        # removed the break
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, and you finding that by loading / saving the file using Excel is somehow repairing your file, then you could use Excel itself to perform this initial conversion. This then should load correctly using your existing code using `xlrd`. For example:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import xlrd

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'input.xls')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(r"output.xlsx", FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
excel.Application.Quit()

# Loading the 'converted' file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('output.xlsx') 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

print('Row',len(sheet.row(3)),sheet.row(3))
# Prints: Row 59 [text:'Client Number', ...
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'll try to tweak the settings and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, NOW it works and I have no clue why. I'll try to figure it out and post an update